# Use Fermat's Theorem to show that for any positive integer $n$, $n^{37}$ - n is divisible by $383838$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Use Fermat's Theorem to show that for any positive integer $n$, $n^{37} - n$  is divisible by $383838$.

**The below is my proof and could you help me if there is any error?**
(I'm not sure about the part for 2,3,7)

First, $383838 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 13 \cdot 19 \cdot 37$.

First, if $n$ is divisible by $37$, since n$^{37}$ - $n$ is the multiple of $n$, it is divisible by $37$.
if $n$ is not divisible by $37$, then by little theorem of Fermat, $n^{37}$ equals to $n \mod {37}$.

therefore it is divisible by $37$.

I can repeat similar processes for $3,7,13,19$ 
since for $19$,
$$n^{37} - n = n ( n^{18} - 1) (n^{18} + 1)$$
and
for $13$,
$$n^{37} - n = n(n^{12}-1) ((n^{12})^2+ \dots )$$
for $7$,
$$n^{37} - n = n(n^{6}-1)(n^{6}+1) ((n^{12})^2+ \dots)$$

and for 3,
$$n^{37} - n = n((n^{2})^{18} + 1^{18})
= n(n^{2}-1)(\dots)$$

and lastly, for 2, $$n^{37} - n = n(n-1)(n^{35}+\dots)$$
since $n, n-1$ are two consecutive numbers,
one of them is even.

Is my proof solid?

Thank you!

Comment: That's some ugly formatting. Use the dollar sign around whole expressions, not just exponents, and when an exponent is more than one digit, put it in braces n^{12}

Comment: Thank you! I just edited it, following your advice!

Comment: Still just using exponents. Don't write "n (dollar sign)^{37}(dollar sign)" write "(dollar sign)n^{37}(dollar sign)". Pretty much all math should be within dollar signs.

Comment: Yes, the proof is solid.

Comment: The idea seems to be ok. Except for $3$ you probably meant to write
$$n^{37}-n=n[(n^{18})^2-1^2]=n(n^{18}-1)(n^{18}+1)$$ et cetera. There was an errorneous sign. As you used the same factorization with $19$, the idea is clear enough, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
(37-1)&\mid(37-1)\\
(19-1)&\mid(37-1)\\
(13-1)&\mid(37-1)\\
(7-1)&\mid(37-1)\\
(3-1)&\mid(37-1)\\
(2-1)&\mid(37-1)
\end{align}
$$

> **Using Fermat:**
>
> For a prime $p$, Fermat says that if $n\not\equiv0\pmod{p}$ then
>
> $$n^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p}$$
>
> Therefore, for any non-negative $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have
>
> $$n^{k(p-1)}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$$
>
> The preceding is true as long as $n\not\equiv0\pmod{p}$. However, we can make this true for all $n$ by multiplying both sides by $n$; Then, if $n\equiv0\pmod{p}$, both sides are $0$ mod $p$:
>
> $$n^{k(p-1)+1}\equiv n\pmod{p}$$
>
> Therefore, as long as $m=k(p-1)+1\equiv1\pmod{p-1}$, we have
>
> $$n^m\equiv n\pmod{p}$$